# Any Word Denoting "participating college lecture without enrollment"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to taking a course in other college in my university without actual enrollment.

I need to mail this request to the professor who is in charge of that class but I don't know how westerners are describing this concept in one word.

Comment: How to close this question ? In application there's no function like that I guess.

Comment: Througj application

Comment: Thx. I was carelss not to search exisiting questions beforhand. Thx again

Comment: Audit the class.

Comment: I stand to be corrected and my belief is that many lecturers will be happy for just-about-anyone to attend one or two classes but to take the whole course, you need to enroll…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin what..?